# Levenshtein distance and modern indexes in Neo4j

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, neo4j, levenshtein-distance

I have been using legacy indexes (aka Lucene) to run queries like the following in Neo4j Cypher in order to go through millions of simhashes in realtime and find similar items:

```
START file = node:File("simhash:THE_SIMHASH_HERE~0.8")
RETURN file.name
```

Since Lucene indexes are being deprecated now, I wonder if there is a way to run similar queries on the modern Label-based indexes.

Comment: Short answer: not yet. Would be great to hear where things like this, wildcard searches, etc. are on the road map.

Comment: You run them the same way until this functionality is added to the new schema indexes.